# compare 2 list of lists partially

Tags: python

I have 2 list of lists:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 8], [1, 3, 3]]
b = [[1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 9], [5, 3, 3]]
```

I want to only get the lists from b that have the same 2 first elements with lists in a
from my example return `[1, 2, 5]` and `[1, 2, 9]`

Comment: Do you want to compare the elements in `b` with all the elements in `a`? or only with the element in `a` with the same index?

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of tuples consisting of the first two values of each list in `a`, then use that to filter the entries in `b`:

```
allowed_prefixes = [(v[0], v[1]) for v in a]
filtered_b = [v for v in b if (v[0], v[1]) in allowed_prefixes]
```

As [Jorge Luis notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76217767/compare-2-list-of-lists-partially/76217853?noredirect=1#comment134408786_76217853) in the comments, using the prefix list to create a set will give the `in` operator a performance boost:

```
allowed_prefixes = {(v[0], v[1]) for v in a}
```

Comment: You can even define `allowed_prefixes` as a set for faster search.

Comment: Forgot to update the text, which still talks about using the prefix list.

Answer (score 0):

You can by using a list comprehension :

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 8], [1, 3, 3]]
b = [[1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 9], [5, 3, 3]]

result = [list_b for list_b in b if list_b[:2] in [list_a[:2] for list_a in a]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a match of sublists at the same positions:

```
matches = [lb for la,lb in zip(a,b) if la[:2]==lb[:2]]
```

if you want matches with any list in `a` regardless of positions:

```
prefixes = { tuple(la[:2]) for la in a }
matches  = [lb for lb in b if tuple(lb[:2]) in prefixes]
```